# Validating a channel ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have this strange problem. I am trying to validate that the channel ID exist in the guild and if it does then I want it to do something. But I just can't get it to work.

Normally `bot.channels.cache.get(args[0])` would return all the channel info, but for whatever reason it always returns `undefined` and I don't understand why. (This was written in Discord.JS 1.12.5 not the latest version)

```
const mongoDB = require("../../utility/mongodbFramework");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const bot = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: "welcome",
    aliases: ["setwelcome", "welcome"],
    description: "Server config",
    args: true,
    maxArgs: 2,
    minArgs: 2,
    cooldown: 1,
    permissions: "ADMINISTRATOR",
    usage: "<channelId> <message>",
    async execute(message, args) {
        const { guild } = message;

        if (!bot.channels.cache.get(args[0]))
            return message.channel.send(
                "Send a valid channel ID. (You can use the `.id` command. Or you could use the Discord developer tools)"
            );

        const channelId = args[0];

        args.shift();
        welcomeMessage = args.join(" ");

        await mongoDB.setWelcome(guild.id, channelId, welcomeMessage);

        message.channel.send(`Channel ID: ${guild.id}, message: ${welcomeMessage}`);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your bot is not the one you've logged with so its cache will always be empty. Try to [get the client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client) from your `message`:

```js
const mongoDB = require('../../utility/mongodbFramework');

module.exports = {
  name: 'welcome',
  aliases: ['setwelcome', 'welcome'],
  description: 'Server config',
  args: true,
  maxArgs: 2,
  minArgs: 2,
  cooldown: 1,
  permissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR',
  usage: '<channelId> <message>',
  async execute(message, args) {
    const { client, guild } = message;
    const channelId = args[0];

    if (!client.channels.cache.get(channelId))
      return message.channel.send(
        'Send a valid channel ID. (You can use the `.id` command. Or you could use the Discord developer tools)',
      );

    args.shift();
    
    const welcomeMessage = args.join(' ');
    await mongoDB.setWelcome(guild.id, channelId, welcomeMessage);

    message.channel.send(`Channel ID: ${guild.id}, message: ${welcomeMessage}`);
  },
};
```

PS: you could also try to [`fetch` the channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) by its ID instead of relying on the cache:

```js
const channelId = args[0];
const channel = await client.channels.fetch(channelId);

if (!channel)
  return message.channel.send( /* ... */)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!